# Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol

Tags: box2d, c++

Здравствуйте, учусь прилинковывать библиотеку к проекту в vs10. Прилинковываю box2d. Прописал пути на .lib и на .h в propertis, но компилятор выдает:

> 1>`LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library`
>
> 1>`App.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall b2World::~b2World(void)" (??1b2World@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl AppMain(void)" (?AppMain@@YAXXZ)`
>
> 1>`App.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall b2World::b2World(struct b2Vec2 const &)" (??0b2World@@QAE@ABUb2Vec2@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl AppMain(void)" (?AppMain@@YAXXZ)`

Как избавиться от ошибки, образовавшиеся при прилинковке библиотеки box2d?

Это из-за неправильной прилинковке? И где можно взять Box2D.lib для релиза?

Comment: Выложите ваш `.vcxproj` файл куда-нибудь типа `pastie` и дайте ссылку.

Comment: Вот http://pastie.org/4761706

Comment: \header only - копия\  => \header_only

Comment: Переименовал, нет толку:

MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: _floor already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(_floor_pentium4_.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: _malloc already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(dbgmalloc.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: _free already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(dbgfree.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: _vprintf already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(vprintf.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(ti_inst.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: __thiscall type_info::type_info(class type_info const &)" (??0type_info@@AAE@ABV0@@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(typ

Comment: Покажите вашу секцию с #include директивами. Там надо их либо поменять местами либо убрать оттуда какой-то из #include

Comment: Не надо менять местами просто cstdio удалите скорее всего оно уже есть внутри одного из файлов на которые ссылается Box2D.h. Четыремя пробелами экранируйте решетку #

Comment: - @igumnov Порядок хэдеров не может влиять на ошибки линковщика. 
- @Alerr Ошибка из вашего последнего комментария из-за того, что `Box2D.lib` и ваш проект, к которому вы линкуете библиотеку собраны с разными `Runtime Libraries` (наверняка у одного `/MTd`, а у другого `/MDd`). Сделайте так, чтобы у каждого проекта эта настройка была одинаковой.

Comment: Удалил, ничего не изменилось...

Comment: Внутри video.h точно нет строки #include <сstdio>?

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать Это надо в propertis? У меня в проекте только .vcxproj... У него менять? Или как менять? Сперва открыть папку с box2d и там в проекте поменять, а затем у себя, так?

Comment: @Alerr

> - Open the project's Property Pages dialog box. For details, see How to: Open Project Property Pages.

> - Click the C/C++ folder.

> - Click the Code Generation property page.

> - Modify the Runtime Library property.

И выставите их одинаковыми в обоих проектах.